# Is it possible to use string matchers in combination with specs2 Json matchers?

Tags: scala, specs2

Inside a specs2 test I'm validating json strings using JSON matchers. I know that it's possible to use regexes to match values like so

```
someJson must */("key")/("(one|other)".r)
```

**Is it possible in a neat way to use other string matchers (e.g. contains)?**

Given this messy example:

```
val someJson = """{"blob": "multiline string
                  |with various line endings"}"""
```

This matcher

```
someJson must */("blob")/contains("various")
```

Looks much cleaner than

```
someJson must */("blob")/"[^v]various.*".r
```

Which isn't the proper expression to use but it might work in this case.

Comment: Is there something specific which you want to do that you can't with regular expressions?

Comment: Well, I can't think of any string matching I can't do with regular expressions. That said, readable tests are dear to me. I'll make the question a bit more clear with an example that would actually be messy with regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is now possible (in specs2-1.12.4-SNAPSHOT and specs2-1.13.1-SNAPSHOT) to use specs2 matchers in addition to simple strings and regular expressions to match values and keys:

```
person must /("p.*".r) */(".*on".r) /("age" -> "33")
person must /("p.*".r) */(".*on".r) /("age" -> "\d+\.\d".r)
person must /("p.*".r) */(".*on".r) /("age" -> startWith("3"))
person must /("p.*".r) */(".*on".r) /("age" -> (be_>(30) ^^ ((_:String).toInt)))
```

Comment: Changing reality for your answer to be accepted, eh. Nice one, looks great!

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it. The tell-tale sign for that capability is a method accepting a partial function, and all methods on JsonMatchers accept `Any`.

Comment: @iwein That is often the case when someone finds something Specs2 doesn't do and let Eric know about it...